# NodeJS - Update an Object with returned Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've been struggling with promises.  No matter how many phrasing of this question I read I can't sort it out.

I have a lab class / function which has a property of deployed (boolean).  I want to check to see if the lab is deployed.  I already have a lab object thus I call lab.isDeployed().  However when this returns - it returns true or false however I no longer can access the original lab object because of this asynchronous 'feature'.

```
function lab(id) {
    this.deployed = null; //This is the property.
    this.isDeployed = function(){
        return isLabDeployed(this.id, this.userID).then(function(data){ 
            return data; //Where Data is a query to determine if its deployed.
        });
}
```

This is called from another method.

```
l.isDeployed().then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.be.equal(false);;
});
```

Should I pass the lab object back to the original method?  IE instead of returning data above, should I update the deployed property and return this?  Or is there another way?  I tried to limit the code as I was hoping for an explanation.

Comment: You can use `var proValue = await isLabDeployed(this.id, this.userID)`

Comment: Essentially you're making asynchronous synchronous then?  I felt that was defeating the purpose / point of being async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
this.isDeployed() = function() {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            isLabDeployed(this.id, this.userID)
                .then((data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
        }
    );
```

Then, you can call the isDeployed function as a promise.

```
this.isDeployed()
    .then((data) => {
        // this is where you use your data.
    });
```

Otherwise, you might want to use async/await

```
const data = await this.isDeployed()
```

Basically you want to resolve the data you get as a promise. You might even be able to do something simple like.

```
this.isDeployed() = isLabDeployed(this.id, this.userId)
```

Comment: Remove the Promise constructor anti-pattern. And the code is simply `this.isDeployed = function () { return isLabDeployed(this.id, this.userID) }`

Comment: @DanD. Thanks a ton for both of your help however I guess I don't fully understand how that won't return a promise and leave me with the original issue?  If isLabDeployed returns a promise - won't I still end up with the properties of the lab being undefined when I return from calling isLabDeployed?

Comment: Not to anyone's surprise - you're both right but I don't understand why it works....

Comment: If you're using the lab from inside the promise resolver, you might be running into a scoping issue. Otherwise, I don't see why your lab would become undefined. Try using arrow notation
`l.isDeployed().then((data) => {expect(data).to.be.equal(false);});`

Answer (score 1):

You're still be able to access `l` object

```
l.isDeployed().then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.be.equal(false);
    console.log(l.deployed) // lab object still accessible here
});
```

Or with async/await:

```
const data = await l.isDeployed()
console.log(l.deployed) // lab object still accessible here
```

Comment: My understanding of then is that I'd still be able to access l but it comes back as undefined....  I thought the scope would include the 'parent' (I don't think that's the right word)?